# Narrow search from search results

Tags: php, database, search

I am trying to narrow search results for a game I'm playing.

I am trying to narrow down my search results by clicking on a particular user that is displayed. Once the user is clicked it need to show all database entries for that user.

**For example.**

My dbase fields are :- `Alliance, User, Might`

When I search for 'Alliance', I currently get a list of all users in that alliance

I want to then click on a particular 'user' and only show the results for that user

This is what I have so far

```
    <?php
     mysql_connect ("localhost","my username","password")  or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db ("my_dbase");

  $term = $_POST['term'];


  $data = mysql_query("select * FROM my_table WHERE alliance like '%$term%' ORDER BY type, alliance, might DESC");

        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>Alliance</th> <th>User</th> <th>Might</th> </tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {

        // echo out the contents of each row into a table

                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['alliance'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['user'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['might'] . '</td>';
                echo "</tr>";
        } 

        // close table>
        echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: *pass user id as get parm then sanitize the get param then use user=get user in query*

Comment: Thanks but am new to this, have no programming background and just don't get it lol. I have been lucky to get this far by reading an infinite number of forums

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a link for user detail page as below,

```
echo '<td><a href="userDetail.php?userID='.$row['id'].'">' . $row['user'] . '</a></td>';
```

Create one new page called `userDetail.php` and just fire SELECT query according to userID passed and there you have it.

Comment: @PaulHesketh well `SO` is not a `freelancing`...we are here to help you if you are doing anything wrong during coding...BTW its not hidden i wrote enough about what `code` would be in `userDetail.php` file...now its ur turn.

Comment: @PaulHesketh what you not getting.?

Comment: I set the query in userDetail.php to 

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mordred13 WHERE user='user'");


I have tried different variations but just get a blank results page

Comment: @PaulHesketh and where is that..??